# What are the differences between BLEU and METEOR?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, comparison, machine-translation, bleu

I am trying to understand the concept of evaluating the machine translation evaluation scores.

I understand how what BLEU score is trying to achieve. It looks into different n-grams like BLEU-1,BLEU-2, BLEU-3, BLEU-4 and try to match with the human written translation.

However, I can't really understand what METEOR score is for evaluating MT quality. I am trying understand the rationale intuitively. I am already looking into different blog post but can't really figure out.

How are these two evaluation metrics different and how are they relevant?

Comment: I heard of BLEU before, but I am not familiar with METEOR. So, by METEOR, you're referring to [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~alavie/METEOR/pdf/Banerjee-Lavie-2005-METEOR.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~alavie/METEOR/pdf/Banerjee-Lavie-2005-METEOR.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

Both BLEU and METEOR are meant to evaluate the overall translation quality. METEOR shows a slightly better correlation with human judgment than BLEU, however, it relies on n-gram alignment between the translation hypothesis and reference that needs language-specific paraphrase tables. The quality of the table heavily influences the evaluation quality. I think BLEU was preferred because of its simplicity and language independence. Nowadays, there are many evaluation metrics that correlate much better with human judgment (such as [BLEURT](https://github.com/google-research/bleurt), [BertScore](https://github.com/Tiiiger/bert_score), or [COMET](https://github.com/Unbabel/COMET)) and they start to be preferred in the MT community (cf. papers: [Tangled up in BLEU: Reevaluating the Evaluation of Automatic Machine ranslation Evaluation Metrics](https://aclanthology.org/2020.acl-main.448/), [To Ship or Not to Ship: An Extensive Evaluation of Automatic Metrics for Machine Translation](https://aclanthology.org/2021.wmt-1.57)).

BLEU score is an average of n-gram precisions, weighted by the so-called brevity penalty that penalizes short high-precision, but low-recall hypotheses.

METEOR computes both precision and recall. Here, the precision corresponds to a proportion of words that are in the hypothesis and are correct. The recall is a ratio of how many words from the translation hypothesis appeared in the hypothesis. To do so, we need to somehow decide which words are correct. This is done by n-gram alignment between the hypothesis and the reference. If there is no exact match between the two, a table of paraphrases is used. To penalize sentences that contain the correct words, but in the wrong order, there is a reordering penalty term that penalizes such sentences.

Both metrics measure the same aspects of the translation, but slightly differently:

1. Precision

   - BLEU: directly via n-gram precision
   - METEOR: directly in the alignment graph
2. Recall

   - BLEU: indirectly via including the brevity penalty
   - METEOR: directly in the alignment graph
3. Fluency

   - BLEU: directly by considering longer n-grams
   - METEOR: indirectly from the properties of the alignment graph

Answer (score 0):

**BLEU** is a widely-used metric for evaluating the quality of a machine translation output by measuring its correlation to reference translations. It is based on n-gram precision.

https://machinetranslate.org/bleu

**METEOR**, on the other hand, is a more advanced metric that also compares a machine translation output to reference translations, but it also takes into account additional information such as synonyms, word forms, and sentence structure.

https://machinetranslate.org/meteor